# SQL server Delete and Select in loop

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-delete

I need help to optimize following code:

```
MegaDelete:
DELETE TOP (1000) 
FROM SCADA.dbo.LOGSUMMATIONDATAENTRIES
where dataclassid IN (SELECT distinct OUTPUTDATACLASSID FROM SCADA.dbo.LIVEDATATABITEM where ENABLED = 0 and TABID =25)
IF @@ROWCOUNT>0 GOTO MegaDelete;
```

The problem is: SQL server is getting slow after executing the loop many times. (There are millions rows in SCADA.dbo.LOGSUMMATIONDATAENTRIES table) So I want to save the result(around 1500 INT values) of

```
SELECT distinct OUTPUTDATACLASSID FROM SCADA.dbo.LIVEDATATABITEM where ENABLED = 0 and TABID =25
```

to a variable which will be used in the loop. I think it will imporve DELETE efficiency.

Can anyone tell me how to write the script? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary table (or a table variable) to store the result of the inner query. You might also want to use a join instead of `in`.

Here is how to use a temporary table for this:

```
SELECT distinct OUTPUTDATACLASSID 
INTO #LIVEDATATABITEM 
FROM SCADA.dbo.LIVEDATATABITEM 
where ENABLED = 0 
and TABID =25

MegaDelete:

DELETE TOP (1000) T
FROM SCADA.dbo.LOGSUMMATIONDATAENTRIES As T
JOIN #LIVEDATATABITEM ON dataclassid = OUTPUTDATACLASSID

IF @@ROWCOUNT>0 GOTO MegaDelete;
```

Please note that an index of the `dataclassid` might improve the performance of this delete as well, and also, every table that has foreign key constraints to the `LOGSUMMATIONDATAENTRIES` is slowing the delete since SQL Server must enforce the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Hi Zohar thank you very much, i will try this solution

Comment: Glad to help :-). You might also want to try changing the number of rows deleted each time.